# First order PDF of a stochastic process

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I've started studying about stochastic processes and I need some help in this question.

A random number generator is making numbers by this process:
First number (X0) is a sample from Normal Standard distribution and then other numbers are generated from

> X(n) = a*X(n-1) + Z(n)

that "a" is a constant in range [0,1] and "Zn" is i.i.d random samples independent from X0 and their distribution is Normal(0,1-a^2).
I need to calculate first order PDF of this process.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check  for keywords  `autoregressive process`  and  `AR(1)`.

Comment: Could you clarify what a "first order PDF" of a process is?  Would you perhaps mean the density functions of the individual variables $X(n)$?  If so, note that (by induction) $X(n),$ being a linear combination of independent Normal variables $X(n-1)$ and $Z(n),$ has a Normal distribution, so all you need to do is compute its mean and variance.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot exacatly I was looking for the density function... I did'nt pay attention to the total distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an the keywords you told me was such a big hint. thank you very much.